# Проверка версии файла

Tags: java, android, json

Есть приложение, которое с помощью json берет данные из txt файла
Файл хранится в директории Android/data и скачивается с сервера
Есть ли какие-то готовые решения для сверки версии файла на сервере и в устройстве, при условии, что версия будет храниться в виде отдельной строки в txt файле

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему?

Comment: Если способ хранения версии строкой в файле не является частью какого-то готового решения для сверки версий файлов, то такого решения нет с вероятностью 99,(9)%. Придётся писать с нуля.

Answer (score 0):

первое что приходит в голову это SharedPreferences. про это можно почитать [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php)

сохраняете "текущую версию" у пользователя.
каждый раз как пользователь запускает приложение сравниваете строки, и если они не равны - обновляете данные и сохраняете в SharedPreferences обновленную ID версии JSON'а.